# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Cocoa Pods error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

[![I just installed Cocoa pods and Firebase and I was working on an email authentication. I received no errors or warnings until I went to build the project, then I got the following (see attached pic). I've been trying to solve it myself for the last hour or so to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe2Zp.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe2Zp.png)

Comment: Open the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj with Xcode

Comment: Yeah I can't believe it was that easy. It solved literally every error. Weird thing is now When I launch the simulator, all I get is a black screen. If I set the initial view to a different screen everything works fine. If I set it to the view that has the Email/PW signup it's all black.